# Segmentation Fault in C when adding an element to array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, assign

I am trying to calculate result of the floor function for floats <= 9999.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
include <stdio.h>   
#include "string.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
int i, j, k;
int x[1000];

for(i = 0; i < 10000; ++i){
    x[i] = i;
}

printf("Enter a float in 0..9999: ");
scanf("%d", k);

tester(x, k);
}

int tester(int* c, int k) {
printf("x[%d] = %d\n", k, c[k]);
}
```

When compiler came to;

```
for(i = 0; i < 10000; ++i){
   x[i] = i;
}
```

it gives segmentation fault;

```
x[i] = i;
```

here.

I have already checked similar questions about assigning segmentation fault but I couldn't find any solution way. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to world of magic numbers in the code. int x[`1000`]; and for(i = 0; i < `10000`; ++i) Time to count 0 digits.

Comment: you indexing 10.000 but your array is 1000. You should change your printf ```Enter a float``` to ```integer``` since ```%d``` in scanf interprets input as decimal.

Comment: `"%d"` (integer in decimal format) is wrong format specifier for `float` – you need to use `"%f"` instead, otherwise undefined behaviour.

Comment: The mismatch between 1000 and 10000 is the reason why one should use constants for – and for iterating over arrays preferrably deduce the size from the array itself: `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `x` is of length 1,000, but you're treating it in the loop as if it's of length 10,000. Accessing `x[i]` for `i` greater than or equal to 1,000 is undefined behaviour because the index is out of the array's range.

Thus, a segmentation fault is occurring because your program is accessing memory that it is not allowed to access.

Answer (score 0):

The variable k is initialised and when getting input "&" is missing in the scanf statement. This might have come under segmentation fault since the value "k" is passed in the function tester(). Generally in C lang, we get input with "&", unless if it is a string you don't necessarily mention that in the scanf statement!!.